# Cheking if the JWT access token is still valid in nextjs middleware | nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js, middleware, next.js13

I'm trying to check if the access token which is added to the request headers(in middleware) is still valid or not by sending a fetch request to the external API.

here is the **middleware.tsx** :

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";

const authUserUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/token/validate/1";

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  //get access to the already created jwt 'access' cookie (the existence of this token is tested and guaranteed)
  const access = request.cookies.get("access")!;
  
  //creating new headers to set for every request containing the new 'access' token
  const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers);
  requestHeaders.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + access?.value);

  //check if user is trying to access dashborad
  if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/dashboard")) {
    //sending a get request to the API to check if the 'access' token in the headers is still valid
    const response = await fetch(authUserUrl, { headers: requestHeaders }); //this is the problem
    if (!response.ok) {
      console.log("headers: ", response.headers);
      //send unauthenticated user to the register page
      return NextResponse.redirect("http://127.0.0.1:3000/register");
    }
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  }
}
```

but currently i get this error when i add the `requestHeaders` as fetch API's `headers`:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 4
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: It is telling you there is unexpected character "<" in your (supposed to be) json on 4th position, therefore it is certainly no JSON. Debug your code with console.log(...)

Comment: @digitalniweb thank you for your response. Is this even the right way to do this? at first i thought cloning the ```request.headers``` and adding the token to it is enough and there is no need to add ```requestHeaders``` to the fetch API headers but that didn't seem to work

Comment: I don't know, what I do is put console.log(...) with crucial data on every line and you'll see where is the problem. Like console.log(access) etc. so you see the data is really what you think it is.

Comment: @digitalniweb Thank you. deleting the last line ```return data``` seem to fix the problem and now cookie validation works fine. though i still don't understand what's wrong with ```response.json()``` which is something we almost always do after a fetch request

Comment: I guess your data isn't json or you should add to requestHeaders requestHeaders.set("Content-Type", "application/json");  Try that with const data = await response.json();